# Understanding BufferStruct + WriteMemoryCallback

Tags: c++, function, libcurl

```
struct BufferStruct
{
char * buffer;
size_t size;
};

// This is the function we pass to LC, which writes the output to a BufferStruct
static size_t WriteMemoryCallback
(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *data)
{
size_t realsize = size * nmemb;

struct BufferStruct * mem = (struct BufferStruct *) data;

mem->buffer = realloc(mem->buffer, mem->size + realsize + 1);

if ( mem->buffer )
{
memcpy( &( mem->buffer[ mem->size ] ), ptr, realsize );
mem->size += realsize;
mem->buffer[ mem->size ] = 0;
}
return realsize;
}
```

I found this [here](http://www.hackthissite.org/articles/read/1078)

What is he trying to do here? Espacially by multiplying those size_t's?
He is trying to show how to export the html code you get to a file.
Why is it necesarry to write a complex (for me) function like that?
Thanks if someone can explain or post some source that can help me understand this :)

Comment: There are several functions in the standard library that use the concept of *number of elements* x *element size* rather than a simple byte count (e.g. `calloc`). This is a callback function along the same lines. All it's doing is copying the provided data into a dynamically expanding memory buffer.

Comment: The arguments are documented in the docs for the CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION that I assume you're using, although you didn't say that... Your excerpt is a piece of an official libcurl example code called getinmemory.c

Answer (score 1):

This code below is the "C" way of doing it.. libCurl is a C library (there are C++ wrappers for it as well):

```
struct BufferStruct
{
    char* buffer;
    size_t size;
};

static size_t WriteMemoryCallback(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *data)
{
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;  //size is the size of the buffer. nmemb is the size of each element of that buffer.
    //Thus  realsize = size * sizeof(each_element).

    //example:  size_t realsize = size * sizeof(char)  or size_t realsize = size * sizeof(wchar_t)
    //Again: size is the buffer size and char or wchar_t is the element size.

    struct BufferStruct* mem = (struct BufferStruct*) data;

    //resize the buffer to hold the old data + the new data.
    mem->buffer = realloc(mem->buffer, mem->size + realsize + 1); 

    if (mem->buffer)
    {
        memcpy(&(mem->buffer[mem->size]), ptr, realsize); //copy the new data into the buffer.
        mem->size += realsize; //update the size of the buffer.
        mem->buffer[mem->size] = 0; //null terminate the buffer/string.
    }
    return realsize;
}
```

That is the "C" way of doing things..

The C++ way is shown below:

```
static size_t WriteMemoryCallback(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *data)
{
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;

    std::string* mem = reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(data);
    mem->append(static_cast<char*>(data), realsize);

    return realsize;
}
```

Then somewhere in your code you do:

```
std::string data; //create the std::string..
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback); //set the callback.
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &data); //pass the string as the data pointer.
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for you reply. I still have a question: why do you have to create these function parameters? If I understand it correctly, you give the curl_easy_setopt function a function pointer as an argument so it uses your write function instead of yours, is that right? So how can I know how my own function has to look like to work with the curl class? Thank you

Comment: I didn't understand your question. These function parameters are defined in the libcurl callback: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html  it means if you want curl to use your function, it must have those parameters (signature). Your function has to look like "WriteMemoryCallback". That is YOUR custom function.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `BufferStruct` is a way to package a data pointer and the data size together. This is a good thing because you certainly don't want to get those confused.

The multiplication is to take `nmemb`, aka Number of Members and `size`, aka Size of One Member to get the complete size. And add one in the realloc to make room for a null string terminator. The null string terminator is just to be safe. After all, the data read by curl could just as easily be a JPEG image as a text file.

The necessity of this function? Well, it collects all of the data that curl has read into a single buffer. This is not really necessary. Instead of a function that writes it to memory you could call `fwrite` to write to a file on each callback. In fact, the function parameters are designed to nearly match `fwrite`.